# Pre select an Item in drop box in Razor

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have this dropdown as shown below and I want to pre select an item based on the available data.  But it doesn't work.  The last option is always selected.

```
<select id = @ids>
    <option value="0" @item.SchoolType == " " ? selected ></option>
    <option value="1" @item.SchoolType == "Primary School" ? selected>Primary School</option>
    <option value="2" @item.SchoolType == "Middle School" ? selected>Middle School</option>
    <option value="3" @item.SchoolType == "High School" ? selected>High School</option>
    <option value="4" @item.SchoolType == "University" ? selected>University</option>
</select>
```

How to fix this issue.

Thanks

RJ

Comment: Try removing the `selected` attribute for all of the options.

Comment: Look at using Html.DropDownList http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Change your code as

```
@(item.SchoolType == "Middle School" ? "selected" : string.Empty)
```

You are not using Ternary Operator properly